# Types of Authentication - Standard Login vs Connected App

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps

I am creating a chrome app right now and am wondering why I wouldn't just run a standard OAuth flow requiring the user to submit their username and password directly to login.salesforce.com to connect their Salesforce account rather than creating a connected app.

I guess I Am really struggling to wrap my head around Connected Apps and Standard Logins. I have seen apps where all I have to do is log in to my salesforce account using my username and password to connect the app. I have also seen others require a connected app.

What is the difference?
Which is more scalable?
Why would I use one over the other?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. All OAuth flows require a Connected App. Perhaps you mean to say that you'll just have the user log in and scrape their Session ID from the window? Or that you'll ask for their username and password, and submit it on their behalf?

Answer (score 4):

> ... run a standard OAuth flow requiring the user to submit their username and password directly to login.salesforce.com to connect their Salesforce account rather than creating a connected app.

You've accidentally conflated two very different authentication strategies.

If an app asks the user to enter their Salesforce credentials *into the app itself* and then authenticates to Salesforce with no further action on the part of the user, that app is performing a SOAP login (*not* OAuth), and is storing the user's raw credentials. This is a very bad practice for a variety of reasons, although security is at the top of the list.

If an app *redirects* the user to the standard Salesforce login window, where the user authenticates, then (on first login) approves the app to use their Salesforce credentials, and is finally redirected back to the app, that's OAuth. The app is storing a token, not the user's credentials. New applications should always be implemented to use OAuth, and creating a Connected App is part of the required setup to perform OAuth flows.

Comment: The first route could also be a connected app hosted/owned by the 3rd party service being authorized.

Comment: It is worth saying that the connected app only need be created once on one org if the branding is the same across all orgs, and the org on which it is created need not have anything to do with the target org(s) being logged in to.

Comment: @PhilW So for an application such as Workbench, do they have a developer org where they host the main Connected App?

Comment: That I cannot say - it may pre-date this infrastructure and may use something that existed before, or it may use some connected app as you queried.